# GLSL: sampler upload only works when unused sampler is removed

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl, framebuffer

Im currently trying to implement deferred shading with framebuffers in OpenGL. The framebuffer itself works perfectly, but when I dont use all uniform samplers in the shader, one of the textures stop working.

This is my fragment shader, a test demonstration of the framebuffer:

```
#version 330 core

uniform sampler2D texCoordTex;
uniform usampler2D texIndexTex;
uniform sampler2D normalTex;
uniform sampler2D positionTex;
uniform sampler2D depthTex;

float linearizeDepth(float depth){
    float n = 0.1, f = 2000;
    return (2*n)/(f + n - depth*(f-n));
}

out vec4 out_Color;

uniform sampler2DArray texArray;

void main(){
    ivec2 texelCoord = ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy);
    vec2 texCoord = texelFetch(texCoordTex,texelCoord,0).xy;
    uint texIndex = texelFetch(texIndexTex,texelCoord,0).x;
    vec3 normal = texelFetch(normalTex,texelCoord,0).xyz;
    //vec3 pos = texelFetch(positionTex,texelCoord,0).xyz;
    float depth = linearizeDepth(texelFetch(depthTex,texelCoord,0).x);

    out_Color = vec4(0,0,0,1);

    if(texelCoord.x < 512){
        if(texelCoord.y < 300){
            out_Color.xyz = 0.5*normal+0.5;     
        }else{
            out_Color.xyz = vec3(texCoord,texIndex/50.0);       
        }
    }else{
        if(texelCoord.y < 300){
            out_Color.xyz = texture(texArray,vec3(texCoord,texIndex)).xyz;      
        }else{
            out_Color.xyz = vec3(depth);        
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the unused line `vec3 pos = texelFetch(positionTex,texelCoord,0).xyz;` is commented out.
The sampler uniform uploads are logged:

```
13/05/2015 15:11:24,317 INFO  [default] ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram: TextureUnit[ name = depthTex, unit = 1] uploaded to shader.
13/05/2015 15:11:24,317 WARN  [default] ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram: glGetError() is GL_NONE
13/05/2015 15:11:24,317 INFO  [default] ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram: TextureUnit[ name = texCoordTex, unit = 2] uploaded to shader.
13/05/2015 15:11:24,317 WARN  [default] ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram: glGetError() is GL_NONE
13/05/2015 15:11:24,317 INFO  [default] ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram: TextureUnit[ name = texIndexTex, unit = 3] uploaded to shader.
13/05/2015 15:11:24,317 WARN  [default] ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram: glGetError() is GL_NONE
13/05/2015 15:11:24,317 INFO  [default] ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram: TextureUnit[ name = normalTex, unit = 4] uploaded to shader.
13/05/2015 15:11:24,317 WARN  [default] ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram: glGetError() is GL_NONE
13/05/2015 15:11:24,317 WARN  [default] ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram: TextureUnit[ name = positionTex, unit = 0] not found in shader.
13/05/2015 15:11:24,317 WARN  [default] ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram: glGetError() is GL_NONE
13/05/2015 15:11:24,318 INFO  [default] ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram: TextureUnit[ name = texArray, unit = 5] uploaded to shader.
13/05/2015 15:11:24,318 WARN  [default] ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram: glGetError() is GL_NONE
```

`positionTex` is of course not found, because it isnt used in the shader.

The result image for the Sponza scene:
[image]

If I dont comment out the line `vec3 pos = texelFetch(positionTex,texelCoord,0).xyz;`, `texCoordTex` doesnt work anymore and the uniform upload creates a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error.

The result looks like this, because the texture coordinates are zero.
[image]

The log output shows the errors:

```
13/05/2015 15:20:26,162 INFO  [default] ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram: TextureUnit[ name = depthTex, unit = 1] uploaded to shader.
13/05/2015 15:20:26,162 WARN  [default] ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram: glGetError() is GL_NONE
13/05/2015 15:20:26,162 INFO  [default] ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram: TextureUnit[ name = texCoordTex, unit = 2] uploaded to shader.
13/05/2015 15:20:26,162 WARN  [default] ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram: glGetError() is GL_NONE
13/05/2015 15:20:26,162 INFO  [default] ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram: TextureUnit[ name = texIndexTex, unit = 3] uploaded to shader.
13/05/2015 15:20:26,162 WARN  [default] ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram: glGetError() is GL_NONE
13/05/2015 15:20:26,162 INFO  [default] ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram: TextureUnit[ name = normalTex, unit = 4] uploaded to shader.
13/05/2015 15:20:26,162 WARN  [default] ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram: glGetError() is GL_NONE
13/05/2015 15:20:26,162 WARN  [default] ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram: TextureUnit[ name = positionTex, unit = 0] not found in shader.
13/05/2015 15:20:26,162 WARN  [default] ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram: glGetError() is GL_NONE
13/05/2015 15:20:26,162 INFO  [default] ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram: TextureUnit[ name = texArray, unit = 5] uploaded to shader.
13/05/2015 15:20:26,162 WARN  [default] ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram: glGetError() is GL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

Am I overlooking something or is this a driver bug?
I use a ATI HD 6870, and I can reproduce this behavior on Linux and Windows.

Comment: To me, this looks like some issue with your management of uniform locations. But without the code, it is impossible to be sure.

Comment: I thought exactly that, but uncommenting this one line in the shader does not change anything on the cpu side, because the uniform location is not found anyway.

Comment: @derhass You were right, I made a mistake. I already made multiple working projects without noticing the bug that I made. You can see it here: http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=2203&cpage=1#comment-133014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug, it was unrelated to the shader. In my `ShaderProgram` class I use `glGetActiveUniform` to find information about the uniform variables. I used the uniform index as location later, but the location must be queried separately by calling `glGetUniformLocation`. The bug is described in [this](http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=2203) blog post.